# How do I fix broken dependencies if apt-get --fix-broken is giving me a "not known" error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, openldap

I've been attempting to install OpenLDAP on Ubuntu, but I keep receiving a dependency error whenever I try to install it.

The console output is:

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-itk:
 apache2-mpm-itk depends on libapache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package libapache2-mpm-itk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apache2-mpm-itk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mpm-itk
 apache2-mpm-itk
```

I tried running the code below to fix these errors:

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

But I received the error:

```
E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known.
```

I have also tried to use the alternative --fix-broken, but I get the same error. Has anyone ever experience this and know a way around this?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll have to resolve the problem with `libapache2-mpm-itk`. There isn't enough info in what you posted above to see why it's failing to install, but a quick workaround would be to just remove it:

`sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mpm-itk apache2-mpm-itk`

After that you should be able to install other packages again.

`-f` has to be used with an action, for example: `sudo apt-get -f install` (you don't need to provide any packages names when doing this.)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

should work to repair damage. You might also find

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

yeilds better result. Even though it's meant to be same.

Comment: second command made actual progress towards something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sudo apt-get -f install` NOT just `sudo apt-get -f`.